# How do I make the square move when a button is pressed on the keyboard? Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make the square move when pressing the "d" button (for example) on the keyboard?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root["width"] = 400
root["height"] = 400

field = Canvas(root)

x = 0
y = 0

def snake(x, y):
    field.create_rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40)
    field.grid(row=x, column=y)
    x += 1
    y += 1
    return(x, y)


root.bind("<KeyPress>", snake(x=x, y=y))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there any reason for `return`ing `x` and `y`. Also, this code doesn't work.

Comment: How do you determine the direction the square should be going? Does the square know "arrow up" mean moving along the y-axis by a certain amount of pixels? Solving this questions for yourself may lead you to your goal.

Comment: @white First, I want to make it move in any direction, and then write movements in different directions with different buttons

Comment: That's why you need a mepping for KeyPress to action. Something along the lines `if key == 'left': do something` for each possible/accepted key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to use `event.char`. It returns the character of the button pressed. Then check which button it was and move it if it is `w,a,s,d` -

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root["width"] = 400
root["height"] = 400

field = Canvas(root)
rect = field.create_rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40)
field.grid(row=0, column=0)

def snake(event):
    x = 0 # Default
    y = 0
    if event.char == 'w':
        y = -10

    if event.char == 'a':
        x = -10

    if event.char == 's':
        y = 10
    
    if event.char == 'd':
        x = 10

    field.move(rect,x,y)


root.bind("<Key>", snake)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you can do it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root.geometry("450x450")

w = 400
h = 400
x = w//2
y = h//2

field = Canvas(root, width=w, heigh=h, bg="white")
field.pack(pady=5)

my_rectangle = field.create_rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40)


def left(event):
    x = -10
    y = 0
    field.move(my_rectangle, x, y)


def right(event):
    x = 10
    y = 0
    field.move(my_rectangle, x, y)


def up(event):
    x = 0
    y = -10
    field.move(my_rectangle, x, y)


def down(event):
    x = 0
    y = 10
    field.move(my_rectangle, x, y)


root.bind("<Left>", left)
root.bind("<Right>", right)
root.bind("<Up>", up)
root.bind("<Down>", down)

root.mainloop()
```

First create `root`, and give `geometry` to it, in this case it is `450x450`.
After that create variables that will store `height` and `width`, and `coordinates x and y`. Then, create `canvas` (`field`) and in `canvas` specify where `canvas` will be located and `geometry` of `canvas` (and `background color`). When `canvas` is created, we create `rectangle`. Functions `left, right, up and down` will cover movement of `rectangle` on canvas. `field.move(my_rectangle, x, y)` - this line of code will move my_rectangle on canvas by x and y, or by left, right up or down, depends what is passed. `root.bind("<Left>", left)` - bind left arrow key to `left function`. Thats why `event` is `parameter` of `fucntion`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root["width"] = 400
root["height"] = 400

field = Canvas(root)

SIZE = 50

class Snake:
    def __init__(self,x,y,canvas):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.direction = (SIZE,0)
    def keypress(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.direction = (SIZE,0)
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.direction = (-SIZE,0)
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.direction = (0,-SIZE)
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            self.direction = (0,SIZE)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.direction[0]
        self.y += self.direction[1]
            
            
            
    def redraw(self):
        self.canvas.delete('snake')
        self.move()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x,self.y,self.x+SIZE,self.y+SIZE,fill="green",tag="snake")
        

def update_screen():
    snake.redraw()
    root.after(1000,update_screen)

snake = Snake(0,0,field)


root.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda event: snake.keypress(event))
root.after_idle(update_screen)
field.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

This uses an object for the snake with methods to react to key presses and redraw the snake. This deletes the existing rectangles and draws new ones rather than moving (might prove more useful for showing the different snake segments).

Advantage of this method, is that the snake can be made to move regardless of whether the user has pressed a button or not. If no button has been pressed the snake will continue in the same direction.

Once you have a more complex game, I'd expect your Snake class to contain a list of the different snake segments that get drawn each time. When the snake moves over a fruit, a new segment is added. See below for a moving snake with multiple segments

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root["width"] = 400
root["height"] = 400

field = Canvas(root)

SIZE = 10

class Snake:
    def __init__(self,x,y,canvas):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.direction = (SIZE,0)
        self.segments = [(self.x,self.y)]
        self.length = 5
    def keypress(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.direction = (SIZE,0)
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.direction = (-SIZE,0)
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.direction = (0,-SIZE)
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            self.direction = (0,SIZE)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.direction[0]
        self.y += self.direction[1]
        new_segment = (self.segments[-1][0]+self.direction[0],self.segments[-1][1]+self.direction[1])
        self.segments.append(new_segment)
        if len(self.segments) > self.length:
            self.segments.pop(0)
            
            
    def redraw(self):
        self.canvas.delete('snake')
        self.move()
        for seg in self.segments:
            
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(seg[0],seg[1],seg[0]+SIZE,seg[1]+SIZE,fill="green",tag="snake")
        #self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x,self.y,self.x+SIZE,self.y+SIZE,fill="green",tag="snake")
        

def update_screen():
    snake.redraw()
    root.after(1000,update_screen)

snake = Snake(0,0,field)


root.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda event: snake.keypress(event))
root.after_idle(update_screen)
field.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient. There's no need to redraw the entire object to move it. The canvas has a `move` method which can be used to move an existing object. In specific case of a snake game, all you need to do is remove the last segment and draw a new segment at the front. . There's no need to move all of the intermediate segments.

Comment: @BryanOakley Agreed. I stopped coding when another answer was accepted.