# How to make the second segment of the snake move after the first? Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to make the second segment of the snake move after the first and adjust it to the same speed?

```
ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ 
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
root["width"] = 400
root["height"] = 400

field = Canvas(root)
oval = field.create_oval(10, 20, 30, 40)
field.grid(row=0, column=0)

rectangle = field.create_rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40)  #First and second segments
field.grid(row=0, column=0)

rectangle2 = field.create_rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40)
field.grid(row=0, column=0)

x = 0
y = 0

x1 = 0
y1 = 0

def move_food():
    global x1, y1
    field.move(oval, -x1, -y1)
    x1 = random.randrange(0, 240, 20)
    y1 = random.randrange(0, 240, 20)
    print(x1, y1)
    field.move(oval, x1, y1)

def check_collision():
    if field.coords(oval) == field.coords(rectangle):
        move_food()
        snake2()
    root.after(250, check_collision)

def position(event):
    global x, y
    if event.char in 'wasd':
        x = 0
        y = 0
        if event.char == 'w':
            y = -20
        elif event.char == 'a':
            x = -20
        elif event.char == 's':
            y = 20
        elif event.char == 'd':
            x = 20

def snake():                            #movement of the first segment
    field.move(rectangle, x, y)
    root.after(250, snake)

def snake2():                           #movement of the second segment, this is where the problem arises, if I understand correctly
    field.move(rectangle2, x, y)
    root.after(250, snake2)

root.bind("<Key>", position)
snake()
check_collision()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not use separate `after()` loops to move the two rectangles.  You should put `rectangle2` to the last position of `rectangle1` after moving `rectangle1` inside `snake()`.

Comment: Hasn't this been asked before? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259229/2323393

Comment: I'd use a list of segments and a for loop to move them all from a single function